# Nativescript getViewById not updating for count down

Tags: javascript, setinterval, countdown, nativescript

So, i am using the timer that i asked about in this question as a count down: [How to stop timer.setinterval with a tap event or leaving page in nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351527/how-to-stop-timer-setinterval-with-a-tap-event-or-leaving-page-in-nativescript/40351921#40351921)

The counter works, all this while i have been using console.log to check if it works and yes it does but i want to make it appear in the xml for the user of that app to see. But the count does not update in the xml.

Here's the code for the view:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" navigatedTo="navigatedTo" navigatingFrom="onNavigatingFrom" actionBarHidden="true">

    <DockLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="black" color="white">
        <Label text="Time remaining: " dock="left" margin="5" />
        <Label id="timeCount" text="" loaded="pageLoaded"></Label>
    </DockLayout>    
</Page>
```

And the js file behind:

```
var time;
var timeKeep = vm.time;
var count = 0;

function timeCountDown () {
    time = vm.time--;                    //this is the value that i need
    console.log("i is " + time);
}  

countId = timer.setInterval(() => {
    timeCountDown();
    count += 1;
    if (count === timeKeep) {
        timer.clearInterval(countId);
        dialogs.alert({
            title: "Time Up!",
            message: "You did not finish the test in time.",
            okButtonText: "OK"
        });
        aemnavigation.goResults(vm.correct);
    }
}, 1000);  



//the two lines below is how i get it to show on the xml

TimeCountScore = page.getViewById("timeCount");
TimeCountScore.text = time;
```

The value of time gets to the view but it's not updated has the value counts down. I console.log(time) to make sure that it still counts.

Comment: to be able to update the `Label` text property you should use `Data Binding` and to bind the text property of the Label with `id="timeCount"`.  More about this you could find in the documentation here - http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-in-xml , where you will also find example how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should you `data binding` that inherits the Observable class, when a property is changed it will update the XML also. For your case, if you still want to keep your practice you can put the `label.text` inside the interval to get it updated:

```
TimeCountScore = page.getViewById("timeCount");

countId = timer.setInterval(() => {
    TimeCountScore.text = time;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It now works the by doing it the way you suggested.

Comment: @Nikolay Tsonev, thanks too. I have read the docs about data binding previously. Just couldn't get it to work using that method, hence the use of the getViewById method. Guesss i'll have to figure it out later.